# how to add linkr button to Editor - TinyMCE

Tags: php, joomla

I want add Linkr button to Editor - TinyMCE.How I can add this,I have installed linkr component but i don't know how it works please suggest me immediately.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

look at this demo :

http://j.l33p.com/linkr/demo

Refer link:

http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/structure-a-navigation/content-links/4010

Comment: error:
Warning: LinkrInstaller::require_once(/home/intranet/administrator/components/com_linkr/defines.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/intranet/administrator/components/com_linkr/install.linkr.php on line 216

Fatal error: LinkrInstaller::require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required '/home/intranet/administrator/components/com_linkr/defines.php' (include_path='.:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/intranet/administrator/components/com_linkr/install.linkr.php on line 216

Comment: Check path to files and permissions.